# Generate different random numbers for each consecutive iteration in java.

Tags: java, random

As in `C` we have  `srand(time(NULL)))` to ensure that the random number which will be generated on next call will be different than the random number generated for current call.

> What i tried is this.

```
Random r=new Random();
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
System.out.println(r.nextInt(1000)); 
}
```

But it may print similat number in consecutive iterations.

I want that it should print different numbers in consecutive iterations.

Are there any predefined methods to achieve this ?

Comment: The first parameter to the `Random` ctor is the seed. There's also the `setSeed` function. [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Comment: You wish that for multiple runs of your code to print different numbers which weren't printed in the previous iterations. Isn't possible to move the random variable in the class as a static member?

Comment: `new Random()` already works like `srand(time(NULL))`

Comment: `srand` has nothing to do with "ensuring that the random number which will be generated on next call will be different than the random number generated for current call".

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to get the integers 1, 2, ..., 100 in a random/shuffled order?

Comment: I believe they want the function to never print the same one twice in a row. E.g. 

1 5 6 7 6 7 is fine.

1 5 6 6 7 4 is not, because 6 is repeated consecutively.

Comment: @Matt ,u are right.

Comment: If Matt is right, you should edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random r=new Random();
int newNumber;
int oldNumber = -1; //Will never be matching the random number.
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    do{
        newNumber = r.nextInt(1000);
    } while (newNumber == oldNumber);
    System.out.println(newNumber));
    oldNumber = newNumber; 
}
```

Essentially, it compares the potential number to be printed to the last number printed, and if they're the same, rerolls the potential number. Does this as many times as it takes to get a non-identical consecutive number.

Comment: newNumber **==** oldNumber, not =